# How can I figure out Android browser version?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, browser

Our company is developing a web application and I have tested it with different browsers. I have noticed that the application does not work on the default internet browser on my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone. However, our developer is unable to find compatibility information, because I cannot tell him the name and version of the browser. It was already installed when I got the phone and it's called "Internet".

I suspect it might be Samsung Internet for Android (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Internet_for_Android), but I have been unable to confirm it or find any version information.

My question is: How can I figure out, what browser this actually is and if it is Samsung Internet for Android as I suspect, what is the exact version that I have installed. (I don't have Google Play installed on my phone.)

Comment: Won't `User Agent String` tell you something or it is reporting something generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Settings
2. Open Apps ( or similar )
3. Swipe across to System Apps, or Enable them in the drop down menu
4. Find Internet and open the app
5. It should show you the Version Number & Package Name,

   4.3 - Example Version

   com.example.company.app

If you can't find it that way, you need to get the package name by opening the APK file like a ZIP file, open manifest as a text file and find the package name statement...

You can also list the packages with another software, this'll show the package names and icon's for easier package identification.

I'm sure you could list all packages on the phone using a terminal emulator, but it's hard to identify the package if you can only see an icon and name.

---

**Once you have the package name,    **

```
com.example.package.name
```

Search it on a reputable search engine like Google, considering it automatically links you to the app on the PlayStore, it should show relevant information as to what the package is.

---

***EDIT***

[Check Browser UA](https://elijahcuff.com/API/checkBrowser)

Here's a link to a simple PHP Browser checker....

Recommended to use User Agent String in Comments by Morrison Chang.

Comment: I found it, but it does not say any package name. It just says "Internet" and Version 2.1.34.90-0_110500_1177524.

Comment: There is also another entry that is called com.sec.android.app.sbrowsertry with a version of 2.1.34.203954, but it has almost no permission, so I think it might not be the right package. However, searching for it leads to Samsung Internet Browser.

Comment: Samsung Internet is aparently based on Chromium. If I could figure out what Chromium version it is based on, that would probably help me sort out the compatibility problem.